# Telerik Radcombox autopost back not firing at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-combobox

Can some one suggest...I am not able to figure out why the autopost back is not happening once i change the index of ddl.

Please advise what am i missing?  Here is the markup:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="ddl" AutoPostBack="true" 
   DataTextField="name" Width="152" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Bindemail"
   DataValueField="name" DataSourceID="DataSource1" AllowCustomText ="true"
   EmptyMessage="Select user..." HighlightTemplatedItems="true" 
   Filter="Contains" MarkFirstMatch="true"/>
```

Comment: <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="ddl" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="name" Width="152"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Bindemail" DataValueField="name" DataSourceID="DataSource1" AllowCustomText ="true"  EmptyMessage="Select user..." HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
 Filter="Contains"  MarkFirstMatch="true"/>

Comment: Note: rather than posting the markup to a comment, you can edit your post and add the markup there.

Comment: Do you use RadAjaxManager or some other Ajax component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AutoPostBack` works for me, but what you may want to try is setting `CausesValidation="false"`, as selecting a value can trigger validation by default.  Setting it to false doesn't cause a validation on postback.

If that doesn't work, try removing properties from the markup to see if there is a conflicting setting, which can happen.  Try removing `AllowCustomText` and `MarkFirstMatch` to see if it's related to that, then Filter, etc.  Just to see if that is the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with a RadDropDownList. Added three of those and only one had this problem. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: adding CausesValidation="false" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Adding CasuseValidation = "false" worked for me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check this

```
protected void Bindemail(object o, Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
```

try this sample code for

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" AllowCustomText="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Bindemail"
OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
<Items>
<telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="RadComboBoxItem1" Value="RadComboBoxItem1">
</telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
</Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Javascript for

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args)
{
__doPostBack('RadComboBox1','');
}
</script>
```

Check this sample

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/unusual-postback-with-radcombobox.aspx